# Is there a any chrome plugin that lets you enter variables for bookmarks?

Tags: chrome

Is there a any chrome plugin that lets you enter variables for bookmarks

When I click on a bookmark I would like it to to ask me to enter a variable before chrome opens the page.

e.g. I bookmark `https://site.<region>.google.com`

When I click on the the bookmark on by bookmarks bar, i am presented with a box where I can enter a variable that `<region>` will be populated with.